# Can one make an expansion in inverse powers of a "perturbation"?

Tags: taylor-expansion, laurent-series

A perturbation $\epsilon$ is by definition a very small "quantity". Therefore, the expansion of say, $(1+\epsilon)^n$ can be given by the well known Binomial series
$$(1+\epsilon)^n = 1+ n \epsilon + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \epsilon^2 + \cdots   $$

Similarly, if one has a $(\mathbf{1} + \textbf{T})^{-1}$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is an identity matrix and  $\mathbf{T}$ such that $|\textbf{T}| < 1$ one can use the [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series)
$$(\mathbf{1} - \textbf{T})^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\textbf{T}^k.$$

Question: Consider now the following expansion given in equation 12 [of this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.12001.pdf)

$$\boxed{ \epsilon^{-1} \left[ \mathbf{1} - \frac{\textbf{T}}{\epsilon} \right]^{-1}= \epsilon^{-1}  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \epsilon^{-k} \textbf{T}^{k} }$$
This expansion seems similar to the Neumann series. However, since $\epsilon^{-1} >>1$, how can this expansion converge? Is it at all a valid expansion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all

$(\mathbf{1} + \textbf{T})^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\textbf{T}^k$ is not correct.

Correct is $(\mathbf{1} - \textbf{T})^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\textbf{T}^k$ if $|\textbf{T}| < 1.$

We have

$$ \epsilon^{-1} \left[ \mathbf{1} - \frac{\textbf{T}}{\epsilon} \right]^{-1}= \epsilon^{-1}  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \epsilon^{-k} \textbf{T}^{k} $$

for $ \epsilon$ with $|\textbf{T}| < \epsilon.$

Comment: Which really means that using the symbol $\epsilon$ here is misleading. Not wrong, because the symbol doesn't inherently mean anything, but actually $\epsilon$ is the "bigger" thing here, not the smaller one, which is the opposite of how we normally write.